# C# LiveCharts Некорректное отображение данных из коллекции на графике

Tags: c#

Есть база данных в виде файла access,с которым работает мое приложение,а именно добавление записей,удаление записей.Эти данные я получаю в DataGridView,после получения в datagrid я их оттуда циклом извлекаю в обычную коллекцию,это данные из столбца "учет за" это даты,после извлечения это коллекция присваивается графику оси X,но они отображаются не по порядке возрастания,а последняя строка вообще не отображается,как исправить эту проблему ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        List<string> y4etza = new List<string>();
        string[] Y4etZa = new string[1000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            y4etza.Add(dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString());


        }

        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Clear();
        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis() { Title = "Учет за", Labels =  y4etza });

    }
```

Видео ролик: [bandicam 2020-05-28 14-34-09-847](https://vk.com/video562029159_456239018)

Comment: Может быть отсортировать список надо?

Comment: Так они изначально в коллекцию извлекаются в том порядке в котором они в DataGrid

Comment: Пройдитесь в дебаге и посмотрите, что возвращает `dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString()` на каждой итерации.

Comment: Возвращает дату ясень пень)) в строковом формате.Свойство Label компонента  LiveChart принимает коллекцию строк